# Is it possible to parameterize the constness of a templated member function?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constants, c++14

Templates make most things about a function signature parameterizable apart from the function name itself. But is it also possible to parameterize the constness of a member function?

Trivial, minimalist, non-templated example:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo *       self()       { return this; }
    Foo const * self() const { return this; }
};
```

vs *straw-man templated hypothetical*:

```
struct Foo {
    template<typename T> T self() std::constness_of(T) { return this; }
};
```

Comment: Your second question should be removed.  It might have but I'm doubtful anyone could prove it.

Comment: It's not super hard to implement this functionality with a specialized base class template, though.

Comment: `const(expr)` would be nice. Along with `noexcept(auto)`

Comment: std-proposals has a few threads about this (spelled `auto_const` or the like). No recent actual papers though.

Comment: @T.c. I think the `const(expr)` is a better system, with `const(auto)` doing some black magic (it becomes a template function on the this type?  Or it auto-writes both overloads?)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not answerable other than by an all-powerful observer of the c++ community.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb the base question is absolutely answerable. And the secondary question has already been answered in the comments.

Comment: Either a question is, or is not answerable. You only have one answer-mark to give, not two for "base question" and "real question". So you need to put sufficient clarification here. For example by saying "Secondary question (if you don't know, it shouldn't prevent you to answer): Has this ever come up in discussion by the c++ standardization community before?". Remember: SO is *not* a discussion forum. People are supposed to answer if they *can* answer, not if they just want to discuss and know answers partially.

Comment: Edited. Sufficient?

Comment: @Catskul yes, I think this solution is beautiful.

Comment: If you hate these repetitions alot, you can always write a macro.

Comment: @T.C. was unable to find reference to `auto_const` any other hints on how/where I might find this discussion?

Comment: I'd like this special behaviour when the name of the first parameter is `this`. In that case, `this` could be implemented as a forwarding reference. `template<typename T> method(T&& this, .. other args ..)`. `T` would tell you the cv-qualifiers, and also whether it's an lvalue or rvalue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But is it also possible to parameterize the constness of a member function?

No, you cannot. You don't have access in the function signature to the implicit object to which `this` points, so you can't dispatch on it or template on it in any way. cv-qualifiers on member functions have to be spelled out.

For more complicated member functions, you could have one invoke the other (typically the non-`const` invoking the `const` one to avoid UB) to avoid some code duplication.

---

Or you could always write a non-member `friend`:

```
struct Foo {
    template <class T,
        std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<Foo, std::decay_t<T>>::value>* = nullptr
        >
    friend T* self(T& x) { return &x; }
};
```

We need the SFINAE to ensure that `self()` isn't found for unexpected types like `Wrapper<Foo>`. Note that this is quite a big longer than your original code, so really only makes sense in the context of having complicated logic.

Would sure be amusing if UFCS was adopted and now we all write our `const`/non-`const` overloads via non-member `friend`s that we still invoke as if they were members.

Comment: Re "You don't have access in the function signature to the implicit object to which this points", that's technically correct but only because the function signature doesn't include the return type. I.e. while the conclusion about templating the constness of a member function (that one can't) is correct, the reasoning isn't.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf It's not the return type that you need... the return type is based on the cv-qualification of `this`.

Comment: Right, the conclusion is correct. But the reasoning (the bit I quoted) is wrong for the function *type*: it's just literally correct, for the function *signature*. Or maybe I'm dumb and you meant to be ultra-precise, but then please clarify for readers the difference between signature and type (I don't think most SO readers will be aware).

Answer (score 1):

In [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40116378/is-it-possible-to-parameterize-the-constness-of-a-template-member-function/40117602?noredirect=1#comment67505752_40116889) on another answer you clarified that

> **”** the goal is to customize constness of the function at will without requiring duplicate code where it's otherwise not needed

The following is one possibility, expressing both `const` and non-`const` versions of a member function in terms of a templated `static` member function.

For the more general case one needs to forward arguments.

Two alternatives are to express the `const` member function in terms of the non-`const` member function, or vice versa. But as I recall that involves a bit of ugly casting. Or some ugliness, not sure (sorry, I'm now sitting on a very limited internet connection).

```
#include <string>

//--------------------------------------- Machinery:

template< class Guide, class Result >
struct With_const_like_t_
{
    using T = Result;
};

template< class Guide, class Result >
struct With_const_like_t_<Guide const, Result>
{
    using T = Result const;
};

template< class Guide, class Result >
using With_const_like_ = typename With_const_like_t_<Guide, Result>::T;


//--------------------------------------- Example usage:

class Bork
{
private:
    std::string s_  = "42";

    template< class This_class >
    static auto foo_impl( This_class& o )
        -> With_const_like_<This_class, std::string>&
    { return o.s_; }

public:
    auto foo()
        -> decltype( foo_impl( *this ) )
    { return foo_impl( *this ); }

    auto foo() const
        -> decltype( foo_impl( *this ) )
    { return foo_impl( *this ); }
};

#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

auto main()
    -> int
{
    Bork v;
    Bork const c;
    v.foo() = "Hi there!";
    #ifdef TEST
        c.foo() = "This assignment to `const` won't compile.";
    #endif
    cout << v.foo() << endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

No, but the work-around is straight forward, and maybe more readable, the intention is clear:

```
struct Foo {
    template<typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_const<T>::value,T> self() const { return this; }
    template<typename T>
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_const<T>::value,T> self() { return this; }
};
```

Comment: It might not have been clear, but the goal is to customize constness of the function at will without requiring duplicate code where it's otherwise not needed. In the minimalist example re-implementation is trivial, in many cases it's not.

Comment: This is obviously way less readable than OP's code... and then instead of calling `x.self()` you'd have to call `x.self<decltype(x)>()` everywhere. -1.